# Converting a table from the JSP to Jquery data table

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, datatable, jstl

I am returning a JSP, which will have a table generated depending on the data attached with the model. I want to convert the table to a JQuery data table after the JSP is loaded. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact I think it may be more adequate do already use a JQuery Datatable in your JSP from the start and not doing any further conversions when JSP is loaded.

If you are to consider that approach, your work would be to create an integration model between your Datatables component and your controller, which I am assuming is Spring MVC since Spring is tagged in your question.

That being said, your roadmap would be something like:

1. Create value objects to move datatables parameters back and forth between your JSP view and your Spring Controller;
2. Create your controller, that are going to handle data requests. This controller must be able to convert your incoming HttpRequest parameters to your value object. If you are indeed using Spring, your Spring Controller would use a customized [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) which are going to read the request and return your VO. This controller must handle your request and retrieve whatever response you might have to provide. Oh, also don't forget to resolve that Resolver in your MVC configuration.
3. Finally, your response would be a JSON, understandable by Datatables.

[This is a great tutorial](http://bthurley.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/spring-mvc-with-restful-datatables/), which I used the first time I needed to implement such integration. Might fill some details for you.

Best regards.